# Change search button in form.mini.phtml to normal button with text?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, rwd-theme, phtml

I am using my own version of the magento 1.9 RWD theme and I want to edit the search at the top so instead of the default search icon there is a button that says 'search' that i can style by myself in CSS. Do I need to edit something in form.mini.phtml? Or how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the RWD theme (I can see in Magento version 1.9.2.4) does style the search button with an icon.

If you re-enable the RWD theme temporarily on local copy of the site you should be able to see the CSS which it uses to style the button.

If you look in /skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css and at line 3687 you should some CSS for  "#search_mini_form .search-button {...." and there is about lines of CSS which styles the button.

Comment: I can see that styles the button but I need to get rid of that icon before I can style it how I want

Comment: I also need there to be text saying something like 'search' in place of the icon

Comment: So what you need to do is copy the styles.css file into your own theme and then remove the styles for "#search_mini_form .search-button:before" and replace it your own style. Also on about line 1121 you need to remove "#search_mini_form .search-button:before" from the list of CSS selectors for " background-image: url(../images/icon_sprite.png);"

Comment: I have had the styles.css copied into my theme from the start. thank you for the help btw. I just tried removing "#search_mini_form .search-button:before" from the sprites part of the css and reuploaded but it somehow made no difference (i have caching disabled while developing the site)

Comment: Ok I had to do it for the @mediascreen css as well even though i thought that was only for the smaller version of the page

Comment: Cool. So you were able to replace the icon ? :)

Comment: I've managed to remove the icon but would now like to replace it with some text and change the width (know how to do that) so its wider to accommodate for the text. Any idea how I can add some simple text saying 'search'?

Comment: If you edit the CSS for "#search_mini_form .search-button" and remove "text-indent" you will see the text "Search" you can then set the width accordingly.

Comment: It looks fine, but it seems that .input-text.required-entry is now has the button overlapping it so if you type in something long the text eventually goes underneath the button, any idea how to make it so the text input box stops before the button? thanks

Comment: Increase padding-right for the .input-text